# How to assign a role to users authenticated through specific web logic provider

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g

Weblogic contains a lot of security providers. It's feasible to make more than one authentication provider active at a time. The problem is we need to assign a different role to the user whenever he is authenticated through one of the providers. Is it possible to assign a specific role to the user each time he got authenticated through one of the providers?

Answer (score 0):

A user can only have a given set of roles at any given time. Roles can be changed in the admin console but can not be done dynamic and for good reason. One would not want an unauthorized user to be able to become the Admin to a server. You can assign all the roles the user requires but you cannot dynamically, using code, perform such compromising tasks.

In short, a user can only perform tasks to the ability that the role provides him at any given time.